# Replace last comma in character with " &"

Tags: r, replace, character

I have many different characters which have the following structure:

```
# Example
x <- "char1, char2, char3"
```

I want to remove the last comma of this character with " &", i.e. the desired output should look as follows:

```
# Desired output
"char1, char2 & char3"
```

How could I replace the last comma of a character with " &"?

Comment: It seems like there is much interest in this topic. Therefore, I have written an article which summarizes the responses of this thread: https://statistical-programming.com/r-replace-last-comma-in-character-with-and-sign Thanks again for all the great responses!

Comment: this is a string not a character, right?

Comment: Ah, no, r calls strings characters. Confusing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option is `stri_replace_last` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_last(x, fixed = ',', ' &')
#[1] "char1, char2 & char3"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `sub` :

```
sub(",([^,]*)$"," &\\1", x)
# [1] "char1, char2 & char3"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could split and unsplit it.

```
u <- unlist(strsplit(x, ""))
u[tail(grep(",", u), 1)] <- " &"
paste0(u, collapse="")
# [1] "char1, char2 & char3"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `str_locate_all` with `str_sub`:

```
library(stringr)
pos <- str_locate_all(x, ',')[[1]][2, ]
str_sub(x, pos[1], pos[2]) <- " &"

# [1] "char1, char2 & char3"
```